# Is it secure to copy packages directly to /var/cache/apt/archives/?

Tags: debian, apt, security

After a fresh install, instead of downloading some .deb packages from a Debian mirror, I would like to copy the files directly from thumb drive to /var/cache/apt/archives/

Would it offer the same security guarantees (in case the files are corrupted) ?
In other words, are the files hashes checked even when taken from cache, or only just after a finished download ?

Should I use a specific chmod / chown for the cached .deb ?

Apt 2.2.4 / Debian 11

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `apt` checks the package files in its cache against its local copy of published hashes before using them, even if they weren’t just downloaded.

To see this, download an old version of `hello` (so the test uses a valid package, just not the right one), rename it (so it pretends to be the current version), and install it:

```
$ wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20141106T162403Z/pool/main/h/hello/hello_2.9-2_amd64.deb
[…]
$ sudo mv hello_2.9-2_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/hello_2.10-2_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install hello
[…]
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hello
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 287 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 hello amd64 2.10-2 [56.1 kB]
Fetched 56.1 kB in 2s (36.3 kB/s)
[…]
```

`apt` silently discarded the invalid package file and downloaded a new one. Checking the installed package’s changelog (`/usr/share/doc/hello/changelog.Debian.gz`) confirms that the installed package is version 2.10-2, not the older one downloaded manually.

(If you try this, purge the package afterwards. It’s small and innocuous but there’s no point in leaving it installed.)

Package files in the cache don’t need any particular permissions as far as I’m aware.

To ensure that your hashes are correct, you should run `apt update` before potentially installing packages from the populated cache.